# How to generate all possible combinations of a string at certain positions?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How would I take a string and replace all occurrences of a given character with all possible combinations of a list of characters?

e.g. string = "GPxLEKxLExx", replace x with ['A','B','C','D','E','F']

Such that it returns:

GPALEKALEAA
GPBLEKALEAA
GPBLEKBLEAA
...
GPFLEKALEAA
...
GPFLEKFLEFF

and all other combinations of these characters.

Based on one of the answers below, this is what worked for me:

```
from itertools import product

input_str = 'GPxLEKxLExx'
input_str = input_str.replace('x', '{}')

outputs = []
for comb in product('ABCDEF', repeat=4):
    outputs.append(input_str.format(*comb))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

input_str = 'GPxLEKxLExx'
input_str = input_str.replace('x', '{}')

outputs = []
for comb in combinations_with_replacement(['A','B','C','D','E','F'], 4):
    outputs.append(input_str.format(*comb))
```

**Edit:** As @Phossel pointed out, the proper function was `itertools.product` instead of `combinations_with_replacement`. So for clarity, the fixed version is:

```py
from itertools import product

input_str = 'GPxLEKxLExx'
input_str = input_str.replace('x', '{}')

outputs = []
for comb in product(['A','B','C','D','E','F'], repeat=4):
    outputs.append(input_str.format(*comb))
```

Comment: This almost does what I want but doesn't achieve all possible combinations as far as I can tell. For example when there is a 'D' in the first x position then the later x values are only replaced with 'D', 'E', or 'F' and not 'A', 'B', and 'C'. When an F is in that first position, only a single string "GPFLEKGLEFF" is returned.

Comment: Switching to the product() iterator from itertools fixed this so instead of combinations_with_replacement(['A','B','C','D','E','F'], 4) I have product('ABCDEF', repeat=4).

Answer (score 0):

```py
myString = "GPxLEKxLExx"
charList = [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
newList = []

for i in charList:
   newList.append(myString.replace("x",i))
```

The value in the newList is the correct answer

Comment: This would only give combinations where all the `x`'s are the same character. I don't think that was what the question was asking.

Comment: OP's  question is to generate all the combinations and replace them

Comment: oh, i just thought 'x' was a fixed value. it's my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
from itertools import combinations
string = "GP{}LEK{}LE{}{}"
l= ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
l2=list(combinations(l, 4))
for i in l2:
    print(string.format(*i))
```

Comment: In the examples in the question, he was using combination with replacements. Also no need to use up extra memory making the `l2` list first. Just let the for loop act on the iterator returned by combinations.